# SharePoint metadata from Office-addin in Office Online

Tags: metadata, office-js, sharepoint-online, office-addins

From Office Desktop we are able to update SharePoint metadata in a document by replacing the Custom XML part inside that document (http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/metadata/properties)
We use Office-js to achieve this.

When trying to do the same from Word Online it does not have a desirable effect. Instead of updating the metadata, it seems metadata in SharePoint and metadata in the Custom XML part are no longer "in sync".

What is the suggested way to update SharePoint metadata from a document opened in Office Online?